# How to pass vuetify components correctly into vueJs component dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this in my data;

```
data(){
    text: 'Go to <v-btn> to="profile">Profile</v-btn>'}
```

Now I need to render this with the html in my component. I tried using this
`<div v-html="text"></div>` but it wouldn't render. What is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you. The v-btn has an extra `>`.

```
<div>
   Go To<v-btn :to="{name:'nameofcomponent'}">Profile</v-btn>
</div>
```

Name of the component will be the name that you've defined in your routes for your component.
For ex:

```
{
 path: "/profile",
 name: "profile",
 component: () => import("path to profile file")
},
```

Comment: Thanks. What will `nameofcomponent` be pointing to ?

Comment: I have the route set up already on route.js and that works. My issue is that I want to dynamically pass the data object into my component.However, the data contains vuetify component (v-btn) which is supposed to be parsed as an HTML tag inside my component so it renders up with the v-btn component rendered as a button.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML), you cannot compose a template using `v-html` and also is it prone to XSS attack.

If you want to compile the template, you can use [v-runtime-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-runtime-template), this will accept your template and compile it to display the vuetify components.

Comment: I'm trying to output the data as real html, which the part you referred me to confirm possible using v-html. It works with conventional html tags like <strong></strong> and <b></b>. However, it doesn't render vuetify components like <v-btn></v-btn>

Comment: Thats right! `v-html` will only render tags and don't compile it. Any data bindings also will not work

Comment: i have suggested you a npm package `v-runtime-template` and i have tested your case it working.